# How does Kendo UI MVVM allow bound fields to have a format?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, formatting

I'm using Kendo ui's mvvm framework, and trying to get an input to apply a format so the number is formatted to two decimal places. Something like:

```
<input type="text" id="myTextbox" data-format="0.00" data-bind="value: variableInMyViewModel" />
```

...but it's not formatting the value. Can you use data-format on an input? If not, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably not use a textbox to take in a number, I would switch to a kendo numerictextbox where you can set the format (n2), and the number of decimals.

```
<input data-role="numerictextbox" data-decimals="2" data-format="n2" data-bind="value: variableInMyViewModel" />
```

See demo at kendoui
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/mvvm

See documentation at kendoui 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox#configuration-format

Comment: It also works with paragraph tag so if you only need to show a numeric value you can do this  <p data-decimals="2" data-format="n2" data-bind="value: variableInMyViewModel" />